# How to enable "Menu primary tabs"?

Tags: routes

I want to enable Menu Primary tabs in my site, but I can't find how to enable them.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: primary tabs as in primary links under menus?

Comment: yes exactly this

Answer (score 1):

1. Under Menus > Primary Links > (select items to enable by checking the menu items)
2. Check to ensure primary links are specified in the blocks by visiting 'Blocks' configuration.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Sorry,I am not looking for this.I am looking how to create Primary tabs under menu,as Primary links exist under menu.And after that how to expose the Primary tabs as a block.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite get your question. By 'Primary tabs' you mean 'Tabbed' sections, with the same links as 'Primary links'?

Comment: I mean "Tabbed sections" with different links from "Primary links".For example,when I create a new node,under Menu settings,at the Parent item drop down list,should be a "Primary tabs" selection(with also Primary links,Secondary links etc).

Comment: Have you tried the http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs module yet?

Comment: With the quicktabs module will I have the choice to select "Primary tabs" as a Parent item when creating a new node?

Comment: You will have the option to select which among the menu links you want to include in the quicktabs. Content/Nodes will follow.

Comment: @jnroche let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/861/discussion-between-sokratis-and-jnroche)